# Infrequent kerberos authentication issue (pam_krb5 vs. pam_unix)

Tags: login, pam, authentication, kerberos

My Linux computer belongs to a company network using a windows domain. The authentication is done using kerberos.

Usually the authentication works fine and I am happy with my linux desktop. But sometimes I have issues to login. After waiting a while (10-20 minutes) and doing some reboots, the login works again.

When the issue occures, tailing the `var/log/auth.log` only gives me this logs when I try to login:

```
Feb 18 07:58:15 localhost lightdm: pam_krb5(lightdm:auth): user naitsirch authenticated as naitsirch@MYCOMPANY.INTERN
Feb 18 07:58:15 localhost lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:account): could not identify user (from getpwnam(naitsirch))
```

The presented password is definitely correct. And pam_krb5 seems to authenticate successfully.

If I enter a wrong password intentionally, I get this log entries:

```
Feb 18 07:58:24 localhost lightdm: pam_krb5(lightdm:auth): authentication failure; logname=naitsirch uid=0 euid=0 tty=:0 ruser= rhost=
Feb 18 07:58:24 localhost lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 18 07:58:24 localhost lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:0 ruser= rhost= 
Feb 18 07:58:24 localhost lightdm: pam_winbind(lightdm:auth): getting password (0x00004388)
Feb 18 07:58:24 localhost lightdm: pam_winbind(lightdm:auth): pam_get_item returned a password
```

Later, after reboot and waiting some minutes, I could login successfully again. In this case I got this logs:

```
Feb 18 08:06:31 localhost lightdm: pam_krb5(lightdm:auth): user naitsirch authenticated as naitsirch@MYCOMPANY.INTERN
Feb 18 08:06:31 localhost lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session closed for user lightdm
Feb 18 08:06:31 localhost systemd-logind[573]: Removed session c1.
Feb 18 08:06:31 localhost lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user naitsirch(uid=10051) by (uid=0)
Feb 18 08:06:31 localhost systemd-logind[573]: New session 10 of user naitsirch.
Feb 18 08:06:31 localhost systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user naitsirch(uid=10051) by (uid=0)
Feb 18 08:06:33 localhost polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:10 (system bus name :1.59 [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/kde/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale de_DE.UTF-8)
```

It looks like `pam_unix` sometimes disturbs `pam_krb5` during authentication process. The user account I am trying to login with, is **not** contained in `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/shadow`.

Any idea why this may happen?